# Are the province names of Japan translatable into English?

Tags: translation, names, old-japanese

When I travelled, I found I could translate the regions or cities into names in English,

- like in German *Burg* is "castle" so Hamburg might be "Castle of Ham",
- Novi Sad in Serbia is "New Farmland",
- Shanghai translates as "Upon-the-Sea".

Do the regions of Japan translate similar? Are there any references to their English names, for example "region of blossoms" or such?

By provinces I mean provinces like *Hōki, Inaba, Harima, Bizen, Mimasaka, Bitchū*, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Chinese and Japanese place names are made of kanji, which is perhaps the most famous sets of [logographic characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logogram) currently in use. Therefore most Japanese place names can be translated literally, just as Shanghai (上海) translates to "upon-the-sea" (上 = up, 海 = sea). For example, [this page](http://ameblo.jp/makoronpop/entry-11494909763.html) has a list of the literal "translations" of the 47 Japanese prefectures.

Comment: I love that page, though I question their spelling.

Comment: Thankyou for A) answering the question and B) providing me with a link so I don't need to DO the translations.

Answer (score 1):

Given that place names are usually written with *kanji* (Chinese logographic characters), it is hard to find a place name that doesn't have a meaning. The "meaning" of a place name is hard-coded into the way it is written.

Often the characters seem to represent the etymology of a place name (京都 "capital city", 大阪 "large hill", etc.).

However, sometimes the characters may have been selected for their phonetic value instead. (This is especially true for old names, from a time when *kanji* were often used for their phonetic value and less for their meaning.)

For example, in the case of the old province 播磨国 *Harima* you asked about, there was more than one way of writing the name: [Wikipedia mentions also 針間国 and 幡麻国](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%92%AD%E7%A3%A8%E5%9B%BD). [Apparently](http://www.geocities.jp/takenet5177/harimasisou.html), the origin of the name *Harima* is unknown. However, with each different way of writing the name, a different meaning is attached:

- 播磨 "polish in large movement"
- 針間 "eye of a needle"
- 幡麻 "hemp flag"

(I don't know how to accurately translate the names.)

Similarly, 美作国 *Mimasaka no Kuni* "Land of Artwork" (remember I'm just making this up) is written with characters that have little to do with the purported [etymology](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%BE%8E%E4%BD%9C%E5%9B%BD#.E7.94.B1.E6.9D.A5) of the place name (御坂の国 "Land of the Sacred Hills", 三坂の国 "Land of the Three Hills", 甘酒の国 "Land of *Amazake*").

In general place names may have adopted different characters for some such reasons. For translation, you have to choose a representation that you use to translate "the" meaning into English.